# Is it possible to catch data streams other than stdin, stdout and stderr in a Popen call?

Tags: python, stream, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I am working on incorporating a program (samtools) into a pipeline. FYI samtools is a program used to manipulate DNA sequence alignments that are in a SAM format. It takes input and generates an output file via stdin and stdout, so it is quite easily controlled via pythons subprocess.Popen().

When it runs, it also outputs short messages to the console - not using stdout, obviously - and I wonder if it would be possible to catch these as well - potentially by getting a os generated handler list?

I guess my question in general is if it is possible to catch a programs console output if it is not coming from stdout? Thank you.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. It is Linux Fedora.

Comment: How are the messages getting to the console, if not through stdout or stderr?

Comment: Your question title is misleading. In the question you only talk about stdout, not stderr and stdin.

Comment: I really don't know. I haven't looked at the source code. I just know that they are not part of the stdout. But I must admit, though, that I have not checked stderror. Is it common to use this for non-error messages?

Comment: Yes, for all kind of out-of-band information, such as progress, debugging information, etc. It's also possible that the program opens `/dev/tty` in a new file descriptor and writes to that, to ensure it writes to the terminal despite any redirection. In that case, intercepting that is trickier as it involves creating a pseudo-terminal.

Comment: @code_onkel. I agree with you. I might fix the title. But then again - if my problem only exists because I never checked stderr (I assumed that it was not the key to my problem), the whole basis for the question falls apart. So, for now I might keep it because it reflects my potential misconception that a program might communicate through other streams than the standard. Others might make the same mistake in which case the title would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other console output than stdout and stderr (assuming that samtools does not write to the terminal directly via a tty device). So, if the output is not captured with the subprocesses stdout, it must have been written to stderr, which can be captured as well using `Popen()` with `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and inspecting the `stderr` attribute of the resulting process object.

Comment: Thank you very much - and I would also like to apologize a little. I feel a bit embarrassed that I did not check stderror. It indeed was the key to my problem. I am wiser now.